# How to fix 'Error in if (nchar(text.matrix[r, c]) > max.length[real.c]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed' using stargazer in rstudio?

Tags: r, stargazer

I'm trying to print a table of combined lm's in Rstudio using Stargazer and I keep getting this message:

> Error in if (nchar(text.matrix[r, c]) > max.length[real.c]) { :
>   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

This is the code I'm using:

```
stargazer(lm_1, lm_2, lm_3, lm_4, 
          dep.var.labels =  c("PolOri_Social_std", "Sexual_Disgust_std"), 
          covariate.labels = c("Gender", "Sexual_Disgust_std"), 
          style = "demography", 
          out = "hierarchical.htm",
          header = F)
```

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: I get the same error. It seems to a bug related to the "covariate.labels" argument. If you delete the covariate.labels argument, the table will print (obviously without renamed covariate labels).

Answer (score 16):

Problem seems to be related to using underscores in the names for covariates. Take these out of them and it should work.

Comment: It can also be caused by the hat `^`

Comment: The same issue arises when there is a line break in the regression equation (that will record as \n).

Answer (score 7):

As others note, the issue arises with special characters in the covariate.labels argument. The recommended solutions, however, miss a few things:

1. With latex output, you can use `\\` to 'escape' special characters so that they appear properly. You can also use the command `xtable::sanitize("Sexual_Disgust_std", type = "latex")` to convert a string to something more latex friendly. In the original example, that would be:

```
`covariate.labels = c("Gender", "Sexual\\_Disgust\\_std")`
```

2. With latex output, some special characters are mathematical and they need to be enclosed in a math mode syntax. For example, if two covariates were % Black and (% Black)-squared, one might write:

```
`covariate.labels = c("\\% Black", "(\\% Black)$^2$")`
```

3. The original question appears to write to a `.htm` file but does not specify in stargazer `type = 'html'` so the default will be `type = 'latex'`. If switching between latex and html output, some of the latex encodings can break the html generation. I'm not aware of an elegant solution to this issue but if you're using `knitr` with R Markdown or Sweave, you could use the functions: `knitr:: is_latex_output()` or `knitr::is_html_output()` to generate latex or html appropriate code as in:

```
    library(knitr)
    library(dplyr)
    library(stargazer)
        
    star_format <- dplyr::case_when(
        knitr::is_latex_output() ~ "latex",
        knitr::is_html_output()  ~ "html",
        TRUE                     ~ "text" # for interactive coding in console
    )
    
    # One way would be to build latex / html specific labels
    covar_labels <- dplyr::case_when(
        knitr::is_latex_output() ~ c("Gender", "Sexual\\_Disgust\\_std"),
        knitr::is_html_output()  ~ c("Gender", "Sexual Disgust std"),
        TRUE                     ~ c("Gender", "Sexual Disgust std")
    )

    # for simplicity, stargazer call doesn't include custom dep.var.labels or out arguments      
    stargazer(lm_1, lm_2, lm_3, lm_4, 
          type = star_format,
          covariate.labels = covar_labels)
    
    
    # A second way would be to create separate stargazer calls:
    if(knitr::is_html_output()) {
    stargazer(lm_1, lm_2, lm_3, lm_4, 
          type             = star_format,
          dep.var.labels   = c("PolOri Social std", "Sexual Disgust std"), 
          covariate.labels = c("Gender", "Sexual Disgust std"), 
          style            = "demography", 
          out              = "hierarchical.html",
          header           = FALSE)
    }
    
    if(knitr::is_latex_output()) {
    stargazer(lm_1, lm_2, lm_3, lm_4, 
          type             = star_format,
          dep.var.labels   = c("PolOri\\_Social\\_std", "Sexual\\_Disgust\\_std"), 
          covariate.labels = c("Gender", "Sexual\\_Disgust\\_std"), 
          style            = "demography", 
          out              = "hierarchical.tex",
          header           = FALSE)
    }
```

4. Using the same `knitr::is_latex_output()` and `knitr::is_html_output()` functions, one could also pre-process any labels with regex to be specifically formatted for html or latex output. For example, below is a small function that would search and replace various special characters text strings.

```
    library(stringr)

    remove_special_chars <- function(covar_labels){
        covar_labels %>% 
            str_replace_all("\\\\", "") %>% 
            str_replace_all("\\^",  "") %>%
            str_replace_all("_",   " ") %>% 
            str_replace_all("\\$",  "") %>% 
            str_replace_all("`",   "'") 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused because underscores (`_`) need to be escaped in Latex and that confuses `stargazer` (even if you're printing text or html).

For me, the easiest solution is to manually take out troublesome characters from labels and pass them to `dep.var.labels` or `covariate.labels`.

```
stargazer(lm_1, lm_2, lm_3, lm_4, 
          dep.var.labels = c("PolOri Social std", "Sexual Disgust std"), # Took out _'s
          covariate.labels = c("Gender", "Sexual Disgust std"))          # Took out _'s
```