# RStudio - Stargazer issue - text table

Tags: text, rstudio, stargazer

I am currently learning RStudio (beginner level) and I have a question regarding `stargazer` function and especially how to create the table of descriptive statistics. I did start by updloading my dataset (called `d`) and all relevant libraries like `stargazer`. I did run command line:

```
stargazer(d, type = 'text', title = "Statistiques descriptives",digits = 1, out="table1.txt")
```

There is an error message:

```
*Error in if (nchar(text.matrix[r, c]) > max.length[real.c]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE / FALSE is required*
```

How can I complete the table with relevant information (mean, standard deviation...) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to describe your data more in detail. Provide a minimal working example, if possible. The command is fine in principle:

```
library(stargazer)

stargazer(mtcars, type = 'text', title = "Statistiques descriptives",digits = 1, out="table1.txt")
```

[image]

Same issue was related to underscore in variable names:

[How to fix 'Error in if (nchar(text.matrix[r, c]) > max.length[real.c]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed' using stargazer in rstudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113706/how-to-fix-error-in-if-nchartext-matrixr-c-max-lengthreal-c-miss)

Please provide `str` of your dataframe.