# How should I fix 'Error in if (nchar(text.matrix[r, c]) > max.length[real.c]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed'

Tags: r, stargazer

I'm trying to print a table of combined lm's in Rstudio using Stargazer and I keep getting this message:

Error in if (nchar(text.matrix[r, c]) > max.length[real.c]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

This is the code I'm using:

````
stargazer(model1.1, model1.2, model1.3, model1.4, model1.5, model1.6,
          title = "The association between talent development and further education",
          dep.var.labels = "Whether to participate in talent development",
          covariate.labels = c("B4.1", "C2_score", "C1_score"),
          type = "html",
          star.cutoffs = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001),
          out = "學才藝與升學.html")``` 

It appears 'Error in if (nchar(text.matrix[r, c]) > max.length[real.c]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed' .

How should I correct it?
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'Error in if (nchar(text.matrix\[r, c\]) > max.length\[real.c\]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed' using stargazer in rstudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113706/how-to-fix-error-in-if-nchartext-matrixr-c-max-lengthreal-c-miss)

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the dependent variables used in the model object "model1.1" are too long.

The stargazer table will be created if you suppress the dependent variable labels from showing.

This can be done by adding

```
dep.var.labels.include = FALSE,
```

to stargazer options.

Since one would probably need some kind of label, my makeshift solution is to add a dependent variable 'caption' instead of a 'label', like so:

```
dep.var.caption="Dep. Vars: (1) (2) Turnout 02-10, (3) (4) Vote Margins 12, (5) (6) Close Elections 12",
```